# Is there a way to refresh all references of all projects in a solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, log4net

I have a visual studio solution that contains many projects, quite often when I take clean check out from a source control (SVN in our case) references are invalid.
I restore Nuget packages (we don't keep them in source control), however some references are still invalid (currently it is `log4net`). Only after manually hitting refresh button for each individual project do the references become valid. 
I am not clear if it is VS issue or particular dll, in any case I am looking for a way to refresh all references of all projects in a solution.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide screenshot? What are "some references"? Do you have project dependencies set up properly?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this, thats your real issue. Are you adding the references to a specific version?

Comment: How do you restore them ?`I restore Nuget packages`

Comment: Are the references in the same exact location, etc? Have you set `Specific version` to `True`? How are you adding the references? Whats the path in the proj file?

Comment: @Sinatr, What do you mean properly? in current case it is log4net nuget package

Comment: @Liam, Yes, specific version, re: location, I use nuget manager so all settings are the same

Comment: @Jehof, via Context menu of a solution "Restore Nuget Packages"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a Visual Studio extension called [Workspace Reloader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ScottHanselman.WorkspaceReloader), it will reload all projects and solutions in your current workspace.

If this is not your issue, if you're talking about invalid/missing NuGet references, you can right click on the solution and select "Enable NuGet Package Restore", which might solve your problem. This makes it so that Visual Studio will automatically download/restore any NuGet packages listed in the solution file/manifest.

Comment: I do not need to reload the projects (it does not help either), only refresh references.